# SQL request in VBA, referencing named range not working

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ado

I'm trying to import data from an excel workbook with multiple sheets that by themself contain multiple tables of data. The goal is to reference a specific table in a sheet by its name and insert it into another excel sheet.
It works if I only reference the sheet ([sheet$]) and if I use specific ranges (e.g. [sheet$A1:C2]) but [sheet$table] does not work for me.

The only additional package I use is "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library"
ERROR:

> Method 'Open' of Object '_Recordset' Failed

Code:

```
Sub GetData() Dim
    
    cn              As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs          As New ADODB.Recordset
    cn.ConnectionString = _
                          "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                          "Data        '';" & _
                          "Extended        'Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES';"
    cn.Open
    rs.ActiveConnection = cn
    rs.Source = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet$Table]"
    rs.Open
    Sheet1.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
    rs.Close
    cn.Close
    
End Sub
```

I would appreciate some feedback for my problem.

Comment: which RDBMS are you using? MySQL,SQL Server,postgresql,..... . tag it correctly

Comment: @RF1991 Where do I find this info? I'm using ADO 2.8

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to pass the sql correctly, currently the `[Sheet&Table]` is part of the string.
Incorporate this in your code and see whether the `MsgBox` gives the correct sql:

```
dim sql = "SELECT * FROM " & [Sheet$Table]
MsgBox (sql)

With rs
    .ActiveConnection = cn
    .Open sql
    Sheet1.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs   
End With
```